# Why does the substitution for the regex fails?

Tags: regex, perl

These snippets seems equivalent to me:

```
$ perl -E '  
my $var="/usr/local/bin/gcc";  
$var =~ s/([^\/]*)$/$1/;  
print "$var\n";'  
/usr/local/bin/gcc  

$ perl -E '  
my $var="/usr/local/bin/gcc";  
$var =~ /([^\/]*)$/;   
print "$1\n";'  
gcc
```

Yet the substitution in snippet 1 does not work. It prints `/usr/local/bin/gcc` instead of `gcc` while the `$1` is correct as the second snippet proves.
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation of *equivalent* is somewhat wrong.  An equivalent to the second example would be to say:

```
$ perl -E '
my $var="/usr/local/bin/gcc";
$var =~ s/.*?([^\/]*)$/$1/;
print "$var\n";'
gcc
```

What you are doing is simply capturing a pattern in a group and *replacing* the thus captured group with itself.  That would have been evident had you tried substituting the match with nothing:

```
$ perl -E '
my $var="/usr/local/bin/gcc";
$var =~ s/([^\/]*)$//;
print "$var\n";'
/usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution is locating the text that matches `[^\/]*` at the end of the string, and replacing it with the matched text (i.e. it is an identity operation).

The second example is only outputting the matched text, ignoring the text at the beginning of the string that doesn't match..

If you want your first example to perform the same action as the second you should try modifying your pattern to: `s/^.*?([^\/]*)$/$1/`

Comment: This prints nothing: `$ perl -E '
my $var="/usr/local/bin/gcc";
$var =~ s/^.*([^\/]*)$/$1/;
print "$var\n";'`

Comment: Right.  I forgot to add a ? to stop the first * being greedy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more portable solution for your special application. It is always a good idea to use core modules to manipulte file paths. So I suggest the following

```
$ perl -MFile::Basename -E '
my $var="/usr/local/bin/gcc";
print scalar fileparse($var), "\n";'
gcc
```